# Remove duplicates in a string in place in JAVA. No additional data structures are allowed

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I recently came across this question and I implemented the same as follows:

```
public class DuplicateRemover
{
    public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str)
    {
        int len = str.length;

        boolean[] hit = new boolean[256];

        for(int i = 0; i < hit.length; i++)
            hit[i] = false;

        int noDupindex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if( !hit[str[i]] )
            {
                str[noDupindex++] = str[i];
                hit[str[i]] = true;
            }
        }
        str[noDupindex] = '\0';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] x = "hhhhhhefffff".toCharArray();
        removeDuplicates(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

But the output shown is "hef hhefffff". The literal '\0' is added to the char array at the end and still while printing it prints the elements after the literal '\0'. Why is it so? Please let me know if I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is not a String object. It's an array of char. When you print an array of char, every element is printed. It does not stop on a null char.

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are not terminated by '\0'. You are thinking of C and C++.

The size of an array cannot be changed after its creation, so `removeDuplicates` can't resize the array. I would recommend that `removeDuplicates` either returns a new array, or just returns a new `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides above great answers, you could also use StringBuilder in java to align with your original intent as this:

```
public class DuplicateRemover
{
    public static void removeDuplicates(StringBuilder str)
    {
        int len = str.length();

        boolean[] hit = new boolean[256];

        for(int i = 0; i < hit.length; i++)
            hit[i] = false;

        int noDupindex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if( !hit[str.charAt(i)] )
            {
                str.setCharAt(noDupindex++, str.charAt(i));
                hit[str.charAt(i)] = true;
            }
        }
        str.delete(noDupindex, str.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("hhhhhhefffff");
        removeDuplicates(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally +1, but you don't need the first `for` loop; Java `new` array sets all elements to `false` for `boolean`, `\0` for `char`, zero for numeric types, or `null` for reference types. If you specify an initializer it *then* sets the initializer values before any code sees the default ones. `new` class does the same thing for fields, except that ctors can see the defaults. Also meta: answers aren't kept in chronological order but are reordered based mostly on votes; to refer to other answer(s) use link(s) (from the 'share' button) or use the answerer's name(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the null character to signify when to print. As immibis pointed out, Java strings are not terminated by the null character.

However you can create a method to adhere to this.

```
public static void printString(final char[] str){
    int length = str.length;
    if(length == 0){
        return;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length && str[counter] != 0){
        System.out.print(str[counter++]);
    }
}
```

You can then just do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] x = "hhhhhhefffff".toCharArray();
    removeDuplicates(x);
    printString(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
public static String trunc(String str) {
    char[] buff = {}, tmp = null;
    boolean found;
    for(char c : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        found = false;
        for(char i : buff) {//search in buff for duplicate
            if(i == c) {//found duplicate
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {//not duplicate
            tmp = buff;
            buff = new char[buff.length + 1];//new array with +1 size for new character
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, buff, 0, tmp.length);//copy tmp into buff
            buff[tmp.length] = c;//store the new character
        }
    }
    return new String(buff);
}
```